# Not able to redirect link pointed to Identity to own action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application with built-in Identity.

The layout page has:

```html
<div class="hidden-xs">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>

        <li><form method="get" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login"><button id="btnLogin" type="submit"  class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Log in</button></form></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="visible-xs">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
        @*<li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>*@
        <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I commented the asp-area code which pointed to Identity to my controller which is the "Account" controller and "Login" method. However on click of login button, it still goes to ../Identity/Account/Login.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you set `[Authorize]` attribute on /Account/Login ?Maybe you could test in a new project or share a demo if it is convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Identity is Middleware so you need to configure in `ConfigureServices` In `Startup.cs` add:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...

    // Add to bottom of ConfigureServices
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = $"/Account/Login";
    });
}
```